# 1 or 2 SSDs for dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I'm going to buy a SSD for my dual boot PC and let the HD for `/home` only. While searching I found a site that offer a discount in the second unity. So I could buy a single 512GB SSD or two 256GB SSD for almost the same price. **Is there a difference between physically or virtually partitioning like that?** Does the performance change at all? Any tip is useful.

Comment: Partitioning isn't virtual ;) Re: the hardware recommendation which is usually frown upon here, that's up to you to decide, there isn't a "right answer".

Answer (score 0):

If you use two SSDs instead of one SSD there may be a reduction in the available disk space due to the requirement for leaving empty disk space on the SSD. *You need some available space for a variety of reasons. If your drive fills up, you won’t be able to save new files to the drive or download anything, including updates. If you have an SSD, leaving at least 25% of the SSD empty will ensure you have excellent performance. On modern SSDs with overprovisioning, this is probably much too conservative, and even 10% could be an OK number. It really depends on the SSD.* <sup>[source](https://www.howtogeek.com/324956/how-much-free-space-should-you-leave-on-your-windows-pc/)</sup>

In general it's easier to manage the disk space when you have fewer disks, and cable management inside the computer case is also more simplified.